# Can't deserialize YAML string array with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, objectmapper

I am trying to map a yaml file into my java object. To achieve this I'm using the jackson ObjectMapper with the YamlFactory.

```
   private JsonNode extractContent(final String url) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper yamlMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());  
        // gitlabHttpService.getAndDecodeFileData(url); -> gets decoded yaml file from gitlab repo as string
        String yamlString = gitlabHttpService.getAndDecodeFileData(url);
        JsonNode jsonNode = yamlMapper.readTree(yamlString);
        return jsonNode;
    }
```

The following code shows the input Yaml String which needs to be converted into a JsonNode or similar.

```
version: '2.0'

nlu:
- intent: Generell, wie melde ich mich an?
  examples: |-
    - [mycompany]{"entity":"category","value":"mycompany"} [hr]{"entity":"subcategory1","value":"hr"} [covid]{"entity":"subcategory2","value":"covid"} Wie kann ich mich anmelden?
    - [mycompany]{"entity":"category","value":"mycompany"} [hr]{"entity":"subcategory1","value":"hr"} [covid]{"entity":"subcategory2","value":"covid"} Wo melde ich mich an?
    - [mycompany]{"entity":"category","value":"mycompany"} [hr]{"entity":"subcategory1","value":"hr"} [covid]{"entity":"subcategory2","value":"covid"} Ich will mich anmelden
    - [mycompany]{"entity":"category","value":"mycompany"} [hr]{"entity":"subcategory1","value":"hr"} [covid]{"entity":"subcategory2","value":"covid"} wie anmelden?
```

But unfortunatly the result looks like the following code snippet and it seems like the ObjectMapper can't identify the YamlArray correctly. It returns just a simple string instead of a list as the examples attribute.

```
{
   "version":"2.0",
   "nlu":[
     {
         "intent":"Generell, wie melde ich mich an?",
         "examples":"- [mycompany]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"postfinance\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Wie kann ich mich anmelden?\n- [postfinance]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"postfinance\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Wo melde ich mich an?\n- [postfinance]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"postfinance\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Ich will mich anmelden\n- [postfinance]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"postfinance\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} wie anmelden?"
      }
   ]
}
```

The expected outcome should look like this:

```
{
   "version":"2.0",
   "nlu":[
      {
         "intent":"Generell, wie melde ich mich an?",
         "examples":[
            "[mycompany]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"mycompany\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Wie kann ich mich anmelden?\n",
            "[mycompany]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"mycompany\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Wo melde ich mich an?\n",
            "[mycompany]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"mycompany\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} Ich will mich anmelden\n",
            "[mycompany]{\"entity\":\"category\",\"value\":\"mycompany\"} [hr]{\"entity\":\"subcategory1\",\"value\":\"hr\"} [covid]{\"entity\":\"subcategory2\",\"value\":\"covid\"} wie anmelden?"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: *examples* is a block scalar, so the value is read into a string. The content doesn't look like YAML at all, so it is unclear what you want to do. Please show the desired output.

Comment: @flyx I've added the expected outcome as you wished. We are using the Rasa framework which uses a slightly different yaml syntax so thats why it doesn't look exactly like usual.

Comment: There's no *slightly different YAML syntax*. Either it adheres to the YAML syntax, in which case you can use a YAML-supporting library like Jackson, or it doesn't, in which case you need to use whatever library can parse your syntax. You want to parse a YAML block scalar's content *partly* as YAML (i.e. parse the `-` sequence item indicators, but not the following text which would be invalid YAML). There's no way to instruct a YAML library to do that. Can you edit the original input?

Comment: Hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110842/13115701